# Using the Propel ORM, how would one delete all related records of an object?

Tags: orm, propel

I have a pretty simple Propel question.  I'm storing leads in a database.  Those leads have one or more community interests.  The tables I'm using are named, 'lead', 'community', and a 'lead_communities' join table.  What's the best way to delete all of a lead's community interests?

Here are some more details.  The Propel schema looks like this:

```
    <table name="community">
      <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
      <column name="name" type="VARCHAR" size="255" />
      <column name="address" type="VARCHAR" size="255" />
      etc...


    <table name="lead_communities">
      <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
      <column name="lead_id" type="INTEGER" />
      <column name="community_id" type="INTEGER" />
      <column name="created_date" type="DATE" size="4" />
      <foreign-key foreignTable="community" refPhpName="Lead_Communities">
        <reference local="community_id" foreign="id"/>
      </foreign-key>
      <foreign-key foreignTable="lead" refPhpName="Lead_Communities">
        <reference local="lead_id" foreign="id"/>
      </foreign-key>      
    </table>  

    <table name="lead">
      <column name="id" type="INTEGER" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
      <column name="salutation" type="VARCHAR" size="20" />
      <column name="first_name" type="VARCHAR" size="255" defaultValue="" />
      <column name="last_name" type="VARCHAR" size="255" defaultValue="" />
      <column name="email" type="VARCHAR" size="255" defaultValue="" />
      etc..
```

Here's how I select the lead from the database:

```
$lead = LeadQuery::create()->filterByEmail($enauk)->findOne();
```

So, what I hope to do is something like:

```
$lead->deleteLeadCommunities();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the easiest way I can think of without any other context is simply doing a query on the join table with a [`delete()` call](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#deleting_objects):

```
$numDeleted = LeadCommunitiesQuery::create()
                ->filterByLead($lead)
                ->delete();
```

Just to be clear, there is no generated method like what you want (`deleteLeadCommunities`), but you could always write it for convenience, and replace `$lead` in my example code with `$this`. So inside `Lead.php`:

```
public function deleteLeadCommunities() {
  return LeadCommunitiesQuery::create()
           ->filterByLead($this)
           ->delete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I love your solution.